# How to return comments that belong to specified post in Neo4j using Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

As I know that in graph database, you don't have to make another same node if you have made it. So I have a same post like this:

```
U.username  P.post
rio         hello
rio         hello
```

As I said before that you don't have to make another same node, So both posts above will be stored in one node. Every node can have some comments. For example, I comment on first post `hello` with `test` like this:

```
U.username  P.post  C.comment
rio         hello   test
rio         hello
```

and I have cypher query language like this to return comments that belong to the first post:

```
MATCH (U:User)-[G:Give]->(C:Comment)<-[H:Has]-(P:Post)<-[S:Shout]-(FU:User)
WHERE P.post_id={post_id} AND FU.user_id={poster_user_id}
RETURN U.username,C.comment
```

If I use cypher above, both first post `hello` and second one will return the same comment that is test but it should be first post `hello` only that should return the comment while the second one shouldn't return the comments that belong to the first post `hello`.

My question is how to return comments that belong to specified post(in this case is the first post `hello`)?

Plase help. If you have others good cypher model, please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your data model, but if you have a node for your user and a node for each post (even if the posts have the same text) your query should work. You'll only get the post that has a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your data model seems weird. Or maybe I don't understand it properly.

My initial thought process on how to model a blog engine would be as follows-

**Types of Nodes (Labels)**
You'll need to have at least 3 types of nodes.

1. User - This holds users in your system
2. Post - These will be the actual blog posts containing the texts
3. Comment - These will contain any comments made by users

**Relationships**
Here is how these nodes will be connected..

- A (User) is connected to (Post) so- (User)-[:AUTHOR]-(POST)
- A (Post) is connected to (Comment) so- (Post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]-(Comment)
- A (Comment) is connected to a (User), so- (Comment)-[:MADE_BY]-(User)

This should be sufficient for a simple blog engine.

**Note:** Each comment for a blog post will be a separate node (I'm not sure of any other approach since it becomes difficult to keep an iterated key in the properties section of a node). If multiple comments are connected to a single node, then you can automatically assume they are comments for that blog post.

Comment: You may not be able to get properly user, post and comments in a single cypher query.. If this model suits you, let me know and ill help you get the cypher query you'll need.

Comment: Thanks for the help. First I want to say I'm sorry because I made you confused. I already got the solution after consultation with my local friends. In my case, I forgot that `2 same informations` couldn't be stored in `one node`. for example `user A` posted `hello` and again `user A` posted `hello`. Two of these `hello` should be stored in `different nodes`, because actually they are `the different things`. Actually that's what I want to consult with you guys.

Comment: And I think `2 same informations` can be stored in `one node` if they only have `one attribute`. for example `user A` works at `Neo4j` and `user B` works at `Neo4j` too. Two of these `Neo4j` can be stored in `one node`, because they are really the same things and have only one attribute, so there is no attributes that can differ between first Neo4j and second Neo4j.

Comment: Hey @arijeet. In your model which way do the arrows go?

(User)-[:AUTHOR]->(POST)
(Post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->(Comment)
(Comment)-[:MADE_BY]->(User)

Like that?

Comment: The direction is up to you. Don't think it really makes a difference. As long as they are connected, you should be able to run cypher queries and traverse the graph.